# How to link a signup with a utm source across multiple steps with google analytics and mixpanel?

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress, analytics

Currently I am running an ad champaign to get users to click on a link to my wordpress site. The link uses `utm_source` code `google-ads`.

Once the user is on the wordpress landing pages, they can click on a signup button which will take them to a web app signup page. The wordpress links to the signup pages uses `utm_source` code `wp-signup`.

On my wordpress site, I use only google analytics.

On my web app site, I use both google analytics and mixpanel.

At the moment in mixpanel I can only see user sign up as a result of `wp-signup`. I am unable to tell if they were redirected from the word press site upstream at all.

So my problem is essentially a **missing link**: how can I link the signup to the those who responded to my google ad?

Will it help if I use mixpanel as well on my wordpress site?